# Cardinality of a generating set of a group?

Tags: group-theory

In a paper that I am reading, the author claims that

> Any group $G$ has a generating set of cardinality $\log|\,G\,|$ or less.

Can someone show the ideas that went into this statement?

The paper, although irrelevant to this particular question, can be found [here](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/iso.pdf) and the statement is the first sentence of section 1.2 on the 4th page of the PDF.

Comment: $\log(G)$ is not well defined. If $|\, G \,|$ is the cardinality of $G$, then I think he/she means $\log |\, G\, | $

Comment: Yes, I actually copied the statement omitting that by mistake (will edit now). Still my question stands.

Comment: Unless he/she's talking about some form of [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)?

EDIT: never mind

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, I am still not sure how discrete logarithm makes the statement any clearer.

Comment: This is answered in the second answer here, I think: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114931/how-can-we-show-that-an-abelian-group-of-order-1024-has-a-set-of-generators-of?rq=1

Comment: @universalset, and what a beautiful answer they gave!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $|G|=n$. Take $e \neq g_1 \in G$ and consider $\langle g_1 \rangle$. Since $g_1 \neq e$, then $|\langle g_1 \rangle| \geq 2$. If $G = \langle g_1 \rangle$ then $G$ is generated by 1-element set, else let $g_2 \in G - \langle g_1 \rangle$. Consider $\langle g_1,g_2 \rangle$. Since $\langle g_1 \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $\langle g_1,g_2 \rangle$ (it should have index at least 2), we obtain $|\langle g_1,g_2 \rangle| \geq 2\cdot2$. What we'll obtain after $\log n$ steps?

Comment: How do we know that we can proceed after step $i$? In other words, what prevents $G-\langle g_1, g_2,\ldots, g_{i-1}\rangle$ from being empty?

Comment: @ijkilchenko: If it is empty then we have a generating set with $i-1$ elements. But anyway $i-1 \leq \log n$.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, $2^{i-1} \leq n$, so the cardinality of the generating set is $i-1$ and $i-1 \leq \log(n)=\log|G|$.